# Plymouth not loading themes on Arch, falls back to three boxes and question marks

Tags: arch-linux, plymouth, bootsplash

I changed the spinner theme image in plymouth to add a custom background, and I tried to load it on boot.

I have changed `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to add the plymouth hook, and run 
`plymouth-set-default-theme -R spinner` multiple times.

[My plymouth debug log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3p3hTQtTH9/)

When I try to test the theme using commands

```
plymouthd
plymouth --show-splash
```

It shows up correctly. But during boot, three boxes are shown near the bottom, with question marks above.
I have tried the same procedure with spinfinity theme, with no luck.

I can't figure out what is going wrong? Some help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: [reddit thread for same question](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/86g51b/plymouth_plymouth_always_falls_back_to_text_theme/). Thanks to [u/kmt1980](https://www.reddit.com/user/kmt1980) for his help. Posting here on his behalf for others who run into this issue.

Plymouth requires Early-KMS init as mentioned in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/plymouth). That is done by adding your VGA driver to `MODULES` in `mkinitcpio.conf`

edit `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and add the driver name to `MODULES=(...)`.
My `MODULES` line looks like this

```
MODULES=(i915)
```

`i915` because Intel integrated graphics. You can find your VGA driver using this command:

```
lspci -v | grep -A10 VGA | grep driver
```

Finally run `mkinitcpio -p linux` to regenerate ramfs.